# Hybrid MySQL/Denormalized datastore to optimize REST API performance

Tags: mysql, rest, symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine

I have a web application built with PHP (Symfony 3) and MySQL (Doctrine).
This is all working well, and now I want to build a REST API to make some parts of the application data public.

To simplify things, lets say I have a */products* page and for each product a details page */product/{id}*.
On the products page, users can apply multiple filters to the product list, such as which categories they want.
Most of the filters are simply a list of checkboxes the user can choose from (no text based filters).

The product table has a lot of relations even though it has not been normalized excessively; this is inherent to the domain I'm working with.
To get all the data for a single product row, I have to do +- 20 joins over 15 separate queries.
Yeah I know, that's a lot, but most tables are just simple lookup tables and the total query time takes only +- 3ms.
The filtering of the products list is done by using a pure SQL query builder.
Because the products page only displays a list of the product names, the performance is no issue here.

But heres the problem: the REST API will have to generate a list of complete product objects with all data (not just names).
As you can imagine, the filtering + all the extra joins/queries and a GROUP BY are not really great for performance.
To solve this issue, I have been thinking about building some kind of hybrid system, only using SQL to write updates to the database, and keeping a readonly denormalized document store to fetch the products from.

The simplest implementation I can think of would be to create a *product_api_cache* table which stores the products generated as JSON, ready to be displayed in the API.
If a user requests the */api/products* resource, the query builder would apply the filters to return a list of product IDs which I can then use to get the products JSON from the *product_api_cache* table.

A more advanced implementation would be to use a proper document store such as ElasticSearch or MongoDB.
I'm not sure how this would fit together with the current filtering system (SQL query builder) though.
Does this mean I have to duplicate all my filtering logic specifically for ElasticSearch?

Also, the JSON the API would return does not 100% map to the actual product object (it gets simplified quite a bit by serializing it).
Does this mean I have to write 2 separate serialization layers? The first one to store a 1-on-1 JSON version of the product object so that ElasticSearch can properly query it, and then the second to serialize the result of ElasticSearch to the simplified view for the user.
Because ElasticSearch returns JSON, does this mean I have to deserialize this result to the product object to then serialize the product object again?

What would be a sensible way to implement this? Are there more ways of doing this? Am I thinking the wrong things?

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest and fastest solution would be storing cached versions of the API response objects. Off course, you will have duplicated data. According to your case, you can decide if its acceptable or not. I wouldn't worry if you don't / won't have database size over several gigabytes. (relative)

If you use elastic search, you have to abstract your filtering logic, as you thought. But you can also use mysql table strategy (id = data) in ES, but that way you would use to ES only to retrieve the data.

And just a reminder. Do you really need that optimization? You may not need it. It is not performance wise, thats for sure. But why complicate the codebase if you not need after all?

Comment: I may indeed not need ElasticSearch right now, but I might in the future for more advanced text searches. While it might be more complex, it could be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on the denormalized table option. If you build a denormalized table to read data, you are basically implementing CQRS (see https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). I did this a few times, the "wrapper object" has the original object as one of their properties, e.g.:

```
class ProductExtended {

    /** @var Product **/
    private $product;

    /** @var float **/
    private $originalPrice;

    /** @var float **/
    private $discountedPrice;

   ...
```

You query your `ProductExtended` entity as any other entity, but in the DB that's a single table so performance are better and filtering is simpler as long as you add to `ProductExtended` all searchable properties.

The effort moves to keeping this table updated: you need to add listeners for any change to `Product`, and probably also a command that rebuild it all to be sure to catch any "manual" or non-listened change.

Comment: This would indeed be a better solution than only storing the JSON, because this wrapper object could also be used outside the API to speed up things.However, I still want the data in the API to be normalized; maybe I could have worded this better. The problem is normalization, but the data itself cannot really be denormalized because it is hierarchical in nature. My first proposed solution would work as a cache, but I don't think this would be possible using CQRS? Essentially what I need is a near exact copy of the product object, but without all the overhead of the joins.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on the ElasticSearch option. If you use ES, you are not required to index the entity "as is". You may build a denormalized version and index **that** version instead, so that you may leverage all advanced filtering options of ES (and no, you cannot get away with a traditional `QueryBuilder` and DQL). The entity ID will be the link between the DB entity and the ES data.

If you have some advanced filtering logic and/or many data, this is a road you may want to explore. ES is very powerful and very fast, and (if correctly integrated with Doctrine) it will return your original entities as results, so it is transparent from the API consumer point of view.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL itself has native [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) support. In fact, it actually also works as a [document store](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/document-store.html) in a similar way to MongoDB.